# Youtube API : Video data at with country information

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am using Youtube Analytics API and want to get a list of all the videos on my account with country information. In the earlier version (V2) I used to get csv files for each video with country information which meant if I have 500 videos on my account I will get 500 files with each file having country column.

I am new to analytics API but looks like I will receive files at video and country level which means that for each video I will have files for each country. For example for video V1 I will have 50 files (for 50 countries) . This would mean that my file count would grow exponentially.

Please provide guidance/help

Comment: Can someone please help. I have a high priority deliverable

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use country as a dimension in your API query. This will give one row per country. For example:

> GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3D{CHANNEL_ID}&start-date=2013-11-01&end-date=2013-11-30&metrics=views&dimensions=country&filters=video%3D%3D{VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Gives number of views by country in November. Change {CHANNEL_ID} to the id of your channel, and {VIDEO_ID} to the id of the video you want to look up. You will have to send a query for each video id to get a country break-down.

Some good docs to read further is the reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/ and the list of available metrics and dimensions: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports

Hope that helps!